# My mapStateToProps is not called after adding custom object array to redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying for few hours but can't figure out why my state is not called after adding an **array** of **custom object**.

```
// In my component...
const myRemoteArray = getRemoteArray() // Is working
props.addAdItems(myRemoteArray) // Calls **1 via component.props
/// ...


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addAdItems: (items) => { // **1
            // Items contains my array of objects 
            dispatch(addAdItems(items)) // Calls **2
        },
    }
}

// My action 
export const addAdItems = (items) => { // **2
    // Items contains my array of objects 
    return { // Calls **3
        type: AD_ITEMS,
        adItems: items,
    }
}

const productsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) { // **3
        case AD_ITEMS:
            // Is working! 
            // action.adItems contains my array!
            const _state = {
                ...state,
                adItems: action.adItems, // Here is the issue, I am not sure how to add my NEW array to existing state and update it. 
                                         // Like that: ??? "adItems: ...action.adItems" or adItems: [action.adItems]
            }

            // The new state contains my Array!!!
            return _state

        default:
            return state
    }
}

// In my component... !!!!
// THIS IS NOT CALLED or it is called with empty array from initialState!!!
const mapStateToProps = (state) => { 
    return {
        updatedItem: state.changedItem,
        adItems: state.adItems,
    }
}
```

It seems to me that Redux is having a problem with my array containing the following data. Has Redux issues with my class methods?

```
class Ad {
    constructor(
        id,
        isPublished
    ) {
        this.id = id
        this.isPublished = isPublished
    }

    someMessage = () => { return "Help me!" }
    needHelp = () => { return true }
}
```

**My Redux is working** already with other calls, data, and objects, which means my `createStore` and all other stuff is correct.

*PS: I don't have multiple stores.*

**UPDATE**
Now my mapDispatchToProps is called with current array but is not persisting.

**UPDATE 2**
If I save my file and force to refresh the App, the `props.adItems` ***contains*** my loaded array, but if I want to access `props.adItems` at runtime (e.g. on FlatList refresh) it is empty array again!

**Why?**
Should I store my array in a useState property after it has changes via useEffect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close in the comments you added in the reducer, but neither of them were 100% accurate.

For Redux to notice that your array has changed, you need the property `adItems` of your new state to return an entirely new array. You can do it like this:

```
adItems: [...action.adItems]
```

With this code you'll be creating a new array, and then adding a copy of the items of the old one into it.

The reason why your current implementation (`adItems: action.adItems`) is not working is that **`action.adItems` is actually a reference to an array in memory**. Even though the array contents have changed, the value of `action.adItems` is still the same, a pointer to where the array is currently stored. This is the reason why your store is not being updated: as **Redux does not check the values of the array itself but the reference to where the array is stored**, the new state you're returning is exactly the same, so Redux is not aware of any changes.

Comment: Hmm make sense, I will test it

Comment: Now my mapDispatchToProps is called with new array but is not persisting.

Answer (score 0):

As LonelyPrincess says, I was making this issue elsewhere, if you doing that `xArray = yArra` it means call by reference and not by value.