# My redux prop gives me empty data after access it from flatList onRefresh

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

If I call my `reload` method for the first time via `useEffect` it contains my data, but if I called via `onRefresh` at runtime, it gives me empty data.

Why? How should I save that? Is it a problem on which thread `onRefresh` is called?

For more information about my item please look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66082400/7905888), maybe it is the same issue.

```
const MyScreen = ({ items }) => {
    const [initialItems, setInitialItems] = useState(items)
   
    useEffect(() => {
        reload()
    }, [])

    const reload = () => {
        console.log(initialItems) // same value 
        console.log(items) // same value 
    }


    return (
        <FlatList
            ...
            refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl
                refreshing={isRefreshing}
                onRefresh={() => reload()} 
                />
            }
            ...
        />
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => { 
    return {
        items: state.items, // I tried this also with [...state.items]
    }
}
```

Comment: is the function reloadData even defined?                 onRefresh={() => reloadData()}

Comment: Yeh sry, is a copy typo here

Comment: something else is changing your state, I don't see anything wrong with your code listed.

Comment: Are you using PropTypes?

Comment: I am not using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was copying my Array like that: `xArray = yArra` it means call by reference and not by value.